# How would I create my own linkage function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I've got a little bit of code that clusters data and builds a dendrogram for me, but I want to replace the `linkage()` function with code of my own, using the single linkage method. I understand in theory how this would work, but I'm having a hard time putting it into Matlab.

Are these steps correct? What would this look like written in Matlab?

1. Define each point in my matrix as a cluster
2. Find the proximity between each of the clusters
3. Group together the two closest clusters as one cluster
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until I reach my threshold

Here's my little bit of code if it's of any use:

```
IMG=imread('Fig_Proc.bmp');
%read the image file
[x,y]=find(IMG(:,:)==15);
%find pixels with a value of 15 (white)
FG=[x,y];
%assign our forground to FG
%BEGIN
tY=pdist(FG);
%calculate euclidean distance of FG coordinates
Y=squareform(tY);
%squareform to get 1241x1241
Z=linkage(Y);
%perform single linkage on our matrix
dendrogram(Z)
%build a dendogram of our data
```

Thanks.